# Rename a file and add a part of the file as the suffix of the file

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, rename

I have file names like:

```
A_20141001_20141224.txt
A_20141002_20141224.txt
B_20141001_20141224.txt
B_20141002_20141224.txt
C_20141001_20141224.txt
C_20141002_20141224.txt
```

I want to rename them to:

```
A_20141001_20141224.txt.20141001000000
A_20141002_20141224.txt.20141002000000
.....
```

Can I achieve this using PowerShell?

I couldn't find answers which picks an item in the existing file and appends it as the suffix to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below bat and it works fine in our environment for your scenario

```
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%I IN (*.txt) DO (
    SET NAME=%%~nI
    RENAME %%I %%I.2014100!NAME:~9,1!000000
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Thanks this works for these files. Is there any way if we can specify the count from the first occurrence of the '_' as file names are all of not same length.